# How to allow multiple Identity Providers on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, saml-2.0

It is straightforward to configure Azure App Service authentication for one of the following authentication sources: Azure AD (federation), Microsoft (local AD), Facebook (OAuth), Google (OAuth) or Twitter (OAuth). I have two questions:

1. Is is possible to allow more than one authentication sources from that list (hence with a Home Realm discovery)
2. Is it possible to add any arbitrary SAML 2.0 Identity Provider?

I don't see a way to do either one via the Portal, but perhaps are there other ways, such as via API?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible the way you're doing (easy auth as it's a module on IIS). You must implement this in your API.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the most desirable option is as follows:

- Your company UIs receive tokens issued only by Azure AD
- Your company APIs receive tokens issued only by Azure AD
- Users can authenticate multiple ways
- Azure AD can federate to other identity providers

**BEWARE OF COMPLEX SOLUTIONS**

Any solution that returns multiple types of token to your UIs and APIs is usually bad. They will add a lot of complexity to your apps.

**AZURE AD FEDERATION**

The goal is for your Azure AD to manage complexity for your apps, and to return a consistent user id regardless of the login method.

There are definitely [working SAML2P options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-saml-idp) - many companies use them for corporate sign in to Office etc

**AZURE APP SERVICE**

Not sure which category this fits into, but it's worth clarifying your goals before choosing the tech. SAML2P is a little complex but tends to be widely used in the corporate world.